# How to fit the figure axes to the data after using 'equal'?

Tags: python, matplotlib, axes

I working with some satellite images. After I extract the data and convert them in arrays, I use matplotlib's `ax.pcolor()` to visualize, and got this after using `plt.axis('equal')`

[image]

How can I fit the figure axes to the data automatically? I can do it manually adjusting the axes dimensions. Is there a better way to do that?

[image]

```py
src = rasterio.open('imagem_teste.tif')
red = src.read(1)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_axes([.1, .1, .465, .8])

ax.pcolor(lon_mtx, lat_mtx, red, cmap = 'jet', shading='auto')

plt.axis('equal')
ax.set_xlabel('Longitude')
ax.set_ylabel('Latitude')
```

Comment: Try `ax.set_aspect('equal')`. Further, you created your `ax` with a fixed box, which doesn't allow matplotlib to make easy adjustments.  The currently recommended way is `fig, ax = plt.subplots()`. Also, [try to avoid `jet`](http://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2014/10/16/how-bad-is-your-colormap/).

Comment: Thank you! It works nicely! And thanks for the 'jet' hint too.